# Woocommerce custom Product slug

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo, slug

Is there a way to create custom product URL based on the product attributes, I have a product sunglasses which has a couple of attributes tied to it: metal, blue and round, so the current URL is:

```
website.com/glasses/sunglasses/abram-widana-629/
```

What I am trying to get is a URL which has those attributes included:

```
website.com/glasses/sunglasses/abram-widana-meta-blue-round-629/
```

I would really appreciate if someone would even just point me to the right direction on how to tackle this.

Comment: This might be helpfull: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/permalinks/ . (haven`t tried it myself).
Maybe you could use the section "Taxonomy Permalinks" with "Product attribute base"

Comment: Product attribute base seems to work like a category, it shows all the products containing selected attribute, but when u click on the actual product the attributes do not stay in the actual URL of the product itself :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, either Manually or Programmatically.

---

## Manually adjusting permalinks:

In your example, you are simply adjusting the product URL to include attributes. This can be achieved manually by editing the permalink on the product itself.

Once the product has been added/saved, you will see the permalink showing directly under the title field like this:

[image]

Simply click the *Edit* button next to it and change it from `abram-widana-629` to `abram-widana-meta-blue-round-629`

---

## Programmatically adding attributes to permalinks:

If you want to try to achieve this permanently for all products you will have to work through the "save_post" filter/hook to add all the attributes to the permalink. The only downfall from this is that you will no longer be able to adjust your individual permalinks for your products as they will simply revert back once you click save.

Below is a code example of how to achieve that:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_custom_attributes_to_permalink', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_attributes_to_permalink( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    //make sure we are only working with Products
    if ($post->post_type != 'product' || $post->post_status == 'auto-draft') {
        return;
    }

    //get the product
    $_product = wc_get_product($post_id);

    //get the "clean" permalink based on the post title
    $clean_permalink = sanitize_title( $post->post_title, $post_id );

    //next we get all of the attribute slugs, and separate them with a "-"
    $attribute_slugs = array(); //we will be added all the attribute slugs to this array
    foreach ($_product->get_attributes(); as $attribute_slug => $attribute_value) {
        $attribute_slugs[] = $attribute_value;
    }
    $attribute_suffix = implode('-', $attribute_slugs);

    //then add the attributes to the clean permalink
    $full_permalink = $clean_permalink.$attribute_suffix;

    // unhook the save post action to avoid a broken loop
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'add_custom_attributes_to_permalink', 10, 3 );

    // update the post_name (which becomes the permalink)
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $full_permalink
    ));

    // re-hook the save_post action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'add_custom_attributes_to_permalink', 10, 3 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, exactly the direction I was looking for :)

Comment: I tried to copy and paste your code to my site. But, it says Parsar Error

Comment: @Jornes that's strange, you shouldn't be getting a parser error with this code at all? And the code definitely works. I'd suggest opening up a new question including the code you are using (this code above), where it was pasted into and the exact error. Feel free to add the link to your new question in the comments here and I will go have a look for you :)

Comment: But it just shows. Not sure why!